# How to integrate Vlc Medial Player Winforms Control into Monodevelop?

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, monodevelop

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to integrate a Vlc medial player control into my project. The project is a C# project using Gtk for GUI controls. I want my project to be cross-platform. Some people recommended Visual Studio Code or whatever it is it doesn't have a support for Linux!
I even tried to add the ActiveX dll library but no luck. After some investigation I found out that Monodevelop will pick only a Gtk control. Monodevelop has no Media controller that I can use.

Any solution for my problem?

Comment: Visual Studio Code works on Linux. It's based on GitHub's Atom and uses Electron Framework which enables you to program JavaScript, HTML, CSS Gui's with Desktop bindings. This works on Win, Mac, Linux ;)

Comment: I can develop GUI with visual studio code? how? Is there a tutorial for that?

Comment: And what do you mean by program Gui's? Do you mean I can design GUI it has a designer?

Comment: I want to be able to design the GUI and see it on a designer view to then program it.

Comment: Visual Studio Code does not have a designer. Iam just saying that Visual Studio Code runs on Linux. If you use Electron Framework you need to know HTML and CSS. Therefore you find enough designer tools which you can use. But Electron has nothing to do with C#. If you want to code C# on Linux you can use Visual Studio Code. If you need a designer you need other tools. Don't know much about Gtk.

Comment: Really? That's too fun that Microsoft saying that Visual Studio Code run on Linux wow without a GUI capability! Anyway thanks for the help I hope someone who have experience would give us some answer to my question to solve the problem.

Comment: Visual Studio Code has not the intention to build up a complete IDE. It's just a lightweight editor like Atom, Sublime etc. It's well for developing webapplications.